# Add 'OR' condition in URL to make a search in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Im making a search query in wordpress with filters without the help of a plugin. It is a property website. I want search to include both the title name and tags hence I wrote this code to give this URL

```
var x= document.getElementById("searchQuery").value;
var y= document.getElementById("filter").value; //Either Buy or Rent
var z="&product_tag=" + x;
window.location ='http://www.mywebsite.com/product-category/' + y + '/?s=' + x + "" + z;
```

It gives this URL when "search" button is clicked:
    http://www.mywebiste.com/product-category/rent-house/?s=london&product_tag=london

Now the problem is search results are only shown when both the "?s=" and "&product_tag" value is found in particular product, whereas I want the value to be found in anyone. Like an "OR" condition.

I searched but couldnt find and "OR" operator to use in URL in place of "&" and operator.

Comment: Unrelated: you need to use `encodeURIComponent` on the strings you pass as parameters Il your URL, otherwise it will break when people type special characters, spaces, or `&` for instance.

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for the reference documentation of `WP_Query` which handles search. Some parameters allow for OR conditions.

Comment: @jcaron The thing is I don't know PHP yet, so was trying it to do it with javascript or jquery. If u can tell quick fix to achieve this "or" condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
var x= document.getElementById("searchQuery").value;
var y= document.getElementById("filter").value; //Either Buy or Rent
var z="+or+product_tag=" + x;
window.location ='http://www.mywebsite.com/product-category/' + y + '/?s=' + x + "" + z;
```

or operator supported in many search engines including StackOverflow

Comment: It is not working in wordpress theme which has woocommerce plugin installed.

Comment: The search itself is used for product search which is made by woocommerce. How can I try without woocommerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you change your mind about using plugins than you might check this solution:

[Search Everything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) plugin can aggregate search results from various sources, in the way "OR" (logical operator) works. After installing this plugin, go to "Dashboard > Settings > Search Everything > 
Search Everything Basic Configuration" and check what you want to include in your search result.

Now you can skip `var z="&product_tag=" + x;` as `'/?s=' + x` will give you results from both title/article **and/or** tags.

Although I didn't test this with filters.

Comment: filter is must. I have to main category with same tags. Hence 'buy' and 'rent' should include in filter. I didn't find any free plugin which works properly.

Comment: I see, but did you try "Search Everything"?